# Docker Backup and restore postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker

I using docker postgres:9.4 image.
I need to know how to backup and restore volume only container.

**Created Volume container:**

```
docker run -v /var/lib/postgresql/data --name dbdata postgres:9.4 /bin/true
```

**Using the volume**

```
docker run --name=postgres --volumes-from=dbdata -d -p 6432:5432 postgres:9.4
```

**Backup Volume container**

```
docker run --volumes-from dbdata -v $(pwd):/backup postgres:9.4 tar cvf /backup/backup.tar /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

**Restore volume in new container**

```
docker run --name=dbdata-new --volumes-from dbdata -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu:14.04 /bin/sh -c 'cd /var/lib/postgresql/data && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar'
```

**Use in the new volume in creating new postgres container:**

```
docker run --name=postgres-new --volumes-from=dbdata-new -d -p 7532:5432 postgres:9.4
```

**Issue:** *I get the below error in the logs when I run the new container.*

initdb: directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" exists but is not empty
If you want to create a new database system, either remove or empty
the directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data" or run initdb
with an argument other than "/var/lib/postgresql/data"

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone please point out where I am making mistake.

Comment: followed your steps and got no errors in the log.

Comment: Add database and tables and  please try

Comment: worked fine with one table in one database, imported and available at postgres-new:

Comment: can you please check if the new postgres instance shows the persisted data

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem, though I went about it differently. I run the PG container with a mounted volume for data, then later had to stop the container, rsync the data to another Docker host, and run a new container with the volume.  Now it's freaking out.  Pretty disturbing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

data-new --volumes-from dbdata -v $(pwd):/backup ubuntu:14.04 /bin/sh -c '**cd /var/lib/postgresql/data && tar xvf /backup/backup.tar**'

The bold text was the problem.
By untaring the backup in the folder /var/lib/postgresql/data ,the tar command was creating /var/lib/postgresql/data inside the above folder.

Thank you for all the help *MyKola*.

Answer (score 2):

Could not easily reproduce the issue following the steps with very rudiment data (one record one table one new db):

```
psql -U postgres -h $(boot2docker ip || echo 'localhost') -p 6432 -c "CREATE DATABASE ttt;"
psql -U postgres -h $(boot2docker ip || echo 'localhost') -p 6432 -d ttt -c "CREATE table a(b int); insert into a(b) values(1);"
psql -U postgres -h $(boot2docker ip || echo 'localhost') -p 6432 -d ttt -c "select * from a;"
```

when I start the `postgres-new` I get no exceptions in logs and the data seems to be there:

```
$ psql -U postgres -h $(boot2docker ip || echo 'localhost') -p 7532 -d ttt -c "select * from a;"
 b
---
 1
(1 row)
```